# Updating Controller $scope property in directive rendered inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a fiddle (it was my first, so was quite a headache to get going!): http://jsfiddle.net/rmN59/17/.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div ng-repeat='d in data'>
    <div id="container-{{ d.key }}">
        <h3>My text {{ d.key }}</h3>
    </div>

    <div class='myDirective' overlay-contents='$parent.overlayContents' name='container-{{ d.key }}'></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay" class="hidden" ng-click="hideOverlay($event)">
    <div ng-bind-html='overlayContents'></div>
</div>
```

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var overlaySelector = '#overlay';
    var showOverlay = function(){
        $(overlaySelector).toggleClass('hidden');
    };

    $scope.data = [{ key: '1' }, { key: '2' }];

    $scope.overlayContents = 'alex';

    $scope.$watch('overlayContents', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal !== oldVal){
            showOverlay();
        }
    });

    $scope.hideOverlay = function(e){
        var target = $(e.target);

        if(target.is(overlaySelector)){
            target.toggleClass('hidden');
        };

        e.stopPropagation();
    };
}]);


myApp.directive('myDirective', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return {
        scope: {
            overlayContents: '=',
            container: '@name'
        },
        template: '<button>Click</button>',
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element){
            var stripAngularProps = function(html){
                return html.replace(/ng-(scope|binding|bind-html="[\w\(\)\.\[\]]+")/g,'');
            };

            element.click(function(e){
                var container = $('#' + scope.container);

                if($(e.target).is(element.find('button'))){
                    var html = stripAngularProps(container.html());

                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.overlayContents = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I have data I need to iterate over and create a directive for each iteration. I then have an overlay directive outside of the loop that will listen for changes to a model on the controller (overlayContents). At which point, the controller will display the overlay with the updated contents.

The $scope.$watch in the controller never fires.

UPDATE: It works in the fiddle! Annoyingly. The only difference I can see is that here I'm using dummy data and in my real project I'm using separate files for the templates. I've been pulling what hair I have left out for hours!

UPDATE 2: The overlayContents property DOES get updated, and it is reflected in the DOM, but the $watch is not called.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what's it that you're trying to do? Is is some sort of editor, where you click a button and it brings the content up in a modal-like window so you can distraction-free edit it?

Comment: Hey man, whether it's working or not - I suggest going over some angular concepts and especially transclution. DOM manipulation should not be done in the controller. Plus, it sounds like what you'r looking for is a transcluded directive (instead of MainCtrl) to wrap the ng-repeat with.

Comment: How are you populating your data - if you are just pushing into the array on scope, that might explain the problem.  $watches are only called when array reference is overwritten on the scope.  Pass 'true' as the second argument to your $watch function to see if it resolves the issue - passing 'true' specifies a deep $watch. If you don't want a deep watch, try overwriting the array reference on the scope instead.

Comment: It's a tool where markup is previewed, then a button can be clicked and a textarea is populated with the final markup. I want this displayed in an overlay. My code is the same as above, I just remove irrelevant stuff for this question. I update the data in the directive in the callback of scope.$apply, this should trigger the $scope.$watch on the same property in the controller. Everything I've read says this should work, and in fact it does in the fiddle.

Comment: If the data that you are using is being loaded it may not be ready when the directives is compiling. I would suggest putting the data load in a promise using $q to get the data to update properly you may need to use a $scope.$apply in order to force an update if it still is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it myself. Sorry for not being able to put more specific code.

By removing the DOM manipulation in the controller and moving it into an overlay directive which watches for changes to the overlayContents this seems to work. Perhaps because the $watch is added in the link function which is after the compile stage. I'm still getting my head round how Angular works.